# MongoDB lookup in multi label nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am very new in MongoDB. I am trying to make lookup in multi label nested array. My data is looks like bellow.

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "621eedae92979fd8f0e9451d",
        "name": "Pallab Koley",
        "shifts": {
            "_id": "62636b9fcbda6d2b17f5cae0",
            "month": "2022-05",
            "shift": [
                {
                    "date": "2022-05-01",
                    "shiftId": "622bb0f4b88dc92e3c2cac56"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "62626a7446ba9a911a623b37",
        "name": "Pinki Das",
        "shifts": {
            "_id": "62636ba4cbda6d2b17f5cae1",
            "month": "2022-05",
            "shift": [
                {
                    "date": "2022-05-01",
                    "shiftId": "622bb0f4b88dc92e3c2cac56"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

And I am trying to run lookup like bellow.

```js
{
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "shifts",
      "localField": "shifts.shift.shiftId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "shifts.shift.shiftId"
    }
  }
```

I am getting the result.

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "621eedae92979fd8f0e9451d",
        "name": "Pallab Koley",
        "shifts": {
            "_id": "62636b9fcbda6d2b17f5cae0",
            "month": "2022-05",
            "shift": {
                "shiftId": [
                    {
                        "_id": "622bb0f4b88dc92e3c2cac56",
                        "name": "Day"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "62626a7446ba9a911a623b37",
        "name": "Pinki Das",
        "shifts": {
            "_id": "62636ba4cbda6d2b17f5cae1",
            "month": "2022-05",
            "shift": {
                "shiftId": [
                    {
                        "_id": "622bb0f4b88dc92e3c2cac56",
                        "name": "Day"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

But my expectation data should looks like bellow.

```json
[
    {
        "_id": "621eedae92979fd8f0e9451d",
        "name": "Pallab Koley",
        "shifts": {
            "_id": "62636b9fcbda6d2b17f5cae0",
            "month": "2022-05",
            "shift": [
                {
                    "date": "2022-05-01",
                    "shiftId": {
                        "_id": "622bb0f4b88dc92e3c2cac56",
                        "name": "Day"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "62626a7446ba9a911a623b37",
        "name": "Pinki Das",
        "shifts": {
            "_id": "62636ba4cbda6d2b17f5cae1",
            "month": "2022-05",
            "shift": [
                {
                    "date": "2022-05-01",
                    "shiftId": {
                        "_id": "622bb0f4b88dc92e3c2cac56",
                        "name": "Day"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Here is `date` field under `shifts.shift` is missing. `shiftId` is replacing all the field under shift array. Please help me out.
[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t3YxW_gH5ls)

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the original content of the array with your lookup result.
Consider using subpipeline to store the date as variable and assign it to the lookup result.

```js
db.employees.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$shifts.shift"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "shifts",
      "let": {
        shiftDate: "$shifts.shift.date",
        sid: "$shifts.shift.shiftId"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              "$eq": [
                "$_id",
                "$$sid"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "date": "$$shiftDate"
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "shifts.shift.shiftId"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bKPVuNqYygx) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I made a mistake to show my requirement. I have changed the play ground with multiple shift. [Modified play ground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b0b72ZZuERb) . And it result should looks like bellow.

```
    {
        "_id": "621eedae92979fd8f0e9451d",
        "name": "Pallab Koley",
        "shifts": {
            "_id": "62636b9fcbda6d2b17f5cae0",
            "month": "2022-05",
            "shift": [
                {
                    "date": "2022-05-01",
                    "shiftId": [
                        {
                            "_id": "622bb0f4b88dc92e3c2cac56",
                            "date": "2022-05-01",
                            "name": "Day"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "date": "2022-05-02",
                    "shiftId": [
                        {
                            "_id": "622b55f8f59dcdd1ab9b36b1",
                            "date": "2022-05-02",
                            "name": "Morning"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "62626a7446ba9a911a623b37",
        "name": "Pinki Das",
        "shifts": {
            "_id": "62636ba4cbda6d2b17f5cae1",
            "month": "2022-05",
            "shift": {
                "date": "2022-05-01",
                "shiftId": [
                    {
                        "_id": "622bb0f4b88dc92e3c2cac56",
                        "date": "2022-05-01",
                        "name": "Day"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```